# How to get Selected Value of DevExpress WPF ComboEdit binded with Entity?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, combobox, wpf-controls, devexpress

I am having a ComboEdit control in my WPF application which is binded by Entity named with 'Contacts'. now i want to ge the selected value of ComboEdit.

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="ddlFirstName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" SelectedIndexChanged="ddlFirstName_SelectedIndexChanged"/>

protected void BindAllDropdown()
    {
        ddlFirstName.ItemsSource = BLL.GetAllContacts();
        ddlFirstName.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
        ddlFirstName.ValueMember = "ContactID";


        ddlLastName.ItemsSource = BLL.GetAllContacts();
        ddlLastName.DisplayMember = "LastName";
        ddlLastName.ValueMember = "ContactID";


    }
```

i am trying to get selected value on selected index change event using:

```
string contid = ddlFirstName.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

this returns whole entity so not able to get the selected value. how to get the selected value?

Help appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ComboBoxEdit.EditValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsBaseEdit_EditValuetopic) property:

```
void ComboBoxEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EditValueChangedEventArgs e) {
    string contid = cb.EditValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: how to set the lastname of combo on firstname changed event? and vice versa & also the selected text from combo?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE This question is not related to the original one (which is already completely answered, I believe).
Please, [do not change the original question dramatically instead of creating new one](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)